# shipping UnityEditor in StreamingAssets for StandAlone use

Tags: unity-game-engine, streaming, editor, assets

I know why I get an error message when trying to build an app that uses the **UnityEditor** directive and I know how to resolve the err msg:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
```

But I am wondering how, for example, the radio button functionality that I need can be included in a **standalone build** then?

If I include the same editor tags and exclude that part of my code to be executed in standalone, I cannot have radio buttons...

The following code implements what I need:

```
int  selGridInt;
string[]  selStrings = { "Male", "Female", "Other" };

case DataFieldType.myRadioButton:
  GUILayout.BeginHorizontal( displayStyle1 );
  selGridInt = GUILayout.SelectionGrid( selGridInt, selStrings, 3, EditorStyles.radioButton );
  GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
  userSelection[i] = selStrings[ selGridInt ];
break;
```

I cannot simply move my script into another folder. How do I resolve this?

I thought maybe I can put the Editor folder into the **StreamingAssets** folder to ship it with the standalone, and then try something like:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
 case DataFieldType.myRadioButton:
   GUILayout.BeginHorizontal( displayStyle1 );
   selGridInt = GUILayout.SelectionGrid( selGridInt, selStrings, 3, EditorStyles.radioButton );
   GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
   userSelection[i] = selStrings[ selGridInt ];
 break;
#elif UNITY_STANDALONE
 string standalonePath = Application.streamingAssetsPath;
 string editorPath = standaloneExperimentPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Editor";
```

But now I need to know how to refer to this script and what to put in my standalone code snippet?

During my search for an answer, I also came across `Resources.LoadAll` and `T[] LoadAll(string path)` in Unity manual, but again the same problem that I don't know how to use this facility in my standalone code. For example, what type is `T` if I just need to use the UnityEditor directive in order to have a radio button function?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you manage to use `UnityEditor` namespace in the build that with some hack, I wouldn't envy the people who would maintain this project. [Of course, you can include executable code in the asset bundles, theoretically (if you don't want iOS)](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/scriptsinassetbundles.html), but what you're trying to achieve can be done much, much easier.

If you want to implement radio buttons, you should be aware that Unity released a new UI some time ago, and I wouldn't advice using `GUI` or `GUILayout` classes for anything except editor scripts and quick debug stuff. [You can find more information about the new UI system here.](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui)

Comment: Thank you Max. The problem is that I have a huge application that cannot be converted to use new UI due to its scale and complexity, as well as the fact that everything is dynamically loaded at run time, so I have to continue using 4.6 as is. But I also need a basic implementation of radio buttons, hence my dilemma! I wonder how other people before the new UI have managed to deal with this problem, because radio buttons do exist in apps that use old GUI code...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only "Editor" functionality you are using is the EditorStyles.radioButton so in order to use this you would need to create the GUIStyle that EditorStyles.radioButton uses.

Unity has an asset you can download from the asset store that has all there default skin textures and a skin you can access and see how it is set up as well

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/5105

That being said you should never use "UnityEditor" code in a release build as this is not supported and probably will never work.  This code is designed to specifically work with the editor and not with anything that is built with the editor.